Is it possible that 2 Thessalonians 2:13-16 is an interpolation?
Could you respond to this? Richard Carrier claims that 2 Thessalonians 2:13-16 is an interpolation. Could someone respond to this? I can't respond myself because I'm not a New Testament scholar. I'll quote it here to this Diehards will then appeal to another passage as their prize counter-example, where indeed Paul appears to say the Jews specifically (no mention of Romans) are the ones who killed Jesus, and then got their just desserts for it: 1 Thess. 2.15-16." But this has long been recognized as an interpolation.
It was not anything Paul wrote. This is not something mythicists cooked up ad hoc. Many well-respected historicist scholars agree, and their case has been made in major peer-reviewed journals. I find their case decisive. Contrary to what this passage states, Paul never blames the Jews for the death of Jesus elsewhere. Paul never talks about God's wrath as having come, but as coming only at the future judgment (e.g. Rom. 2.5; 3.5-6; 4.15); and Paul teaches the Jews will be saved, not destroyed (e.g. Rom. 11.25-28). Most importantly, Paul was almost certainly dead by the time the "wrath had come upon [the Jews of Judea] to the uttermost," a statement that can only refer to the destruction of the Jewish nation and temple in 70 CE. So, obviously, Paul can't have said any such thing.
Its attempts to defend this passage's authenticity are wholly untenable. It requires us to believe too many improbable things. The present text: Richard Carrier's weak argument against one Thessalonians is authenticity. He denies Jesus ever existed.
Would you guys respond to Richard Carrier here?

What you have put is wide ranging. Could you narrow it down to one focal point based on a stated Bible quote?

@Daniel ,,,, In addition to narrowing the question, I'd suggest you try do adopt a less argumentative tone. For example you refer to people who don't share your view as  "diehards" and "mythicists," etc. We try to create a culture of collegiality here, were all views are welcome as long as they take the text seriously.  You have the makings of several good questions here, so I encourage you to keep trying.

This Wikipedia article on Richard Carrier may be relevant to anybody who wishes to delve into the claims of this historian who denies the historicity of Jesus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Carrier#Celestial_Jesus

Incidentally, according to Dr. Gary Habermas, nearly ALL New Testament scholars, even secular ones, agree that Jesus existed, was crucified, and convincingly appeared to his disciples after his crucifixion.

As I understand it, the OP's main question is about whether 1 Thessalonians 2:15-16 is an interpolation. Richard Carrier is not alone in affirming this opinion. According to the Interpreters Bible, it is  affirmed by many scholars. There are several arguments that support this view but there are also good arguments against it.
Pro

The passage interrupts the natural flow of Paul's thought, in which he is expressing gratitude to the Thessalonians. The passage should read:


And for this reason we too give thanks to God unceasingly, that, in
receiving the word of God from hearing us, you received not a human
word but, as it truly is, the word of God, which is now at work in you
who believe... Brothers, when we were bereft of you for a short time,
in person, not in heart, we were all the more eager in our great
desire to see you in person.


The passage is anachronistic. "The wrath of God has finally come upon them to the uttermost" (KJV) is a reference to the destruction of Jerusalem by the Romans in 70 c.e., and thus could not have been written by Paul.

The virulent anti-Judaism of the the passage is uncharacteristic of Paul, who does not elsewhere blame the Jews in such dramatic language.


Con

Although the passage does seem to interrupt the flow of Paul's thought, this can be explained by his awareness of the Thessalonians' suffering, which he felt compelled to mention at this point in writing his letter.

The passage does not refer the destruction of Jerusalem but to an earlier event. A plausible explanation is that Paul refers to the death in 44 c.e. of Agrippa I (who had persecuted the Christians) and the consequent action of Rome to return Judea to the rule of Roman procurators. See my suggestion here for additional data.

The strong anti-Jewish sentiment expressed here by Paul is indeed uncharacteristic of his attitude toward the Jews in general but not of his attitude toward particular Jews such the "Judaizers" and others. So we know that Paul was capable of expressing momentary feelings of strong antagonism, of which this may be an example.


Conclusion: There are good arguments on both sides of the question as to whether 1 Thessalonians 2:15-16 is an interpolation

Instead of "the Jews" being treated as a unified ethnicity, the nation of Israel at that time was deeply divided into three groups: Judeans, Samaritans, and Galileans. Many scholars recognize (and some translations at least footnote) that biblical references to "the Jews" could/should be translated Judeans in reference to the Judean politico-religious leadership. As you noted, what Paul referenced isn't clear and isn't necessarily anachronistic.

Although 1 Thessalonians 2:15-16 could still be a reference to Israel's yet future wrath (Daniel's 70th week), I believe Paul is referring more here to them now being in their fallen state with God, not necessarily THE wrath to come.
They were (and will be) God's chosen people, but they lost their chance (temporarily) to become the kingdom of priests to the world as was promised (Exodus 19:6).  They are presently equal to us Gentile "dogs" (Matthew 15:26-27), the "uttermost" wrath in reference I believe.  They will not be in their elevated status again until after they "endure" their final seven prophetic years of tribulation, and then upon Christ physically returning to earth when their "times of refreshing shall come from the presence of the Lord." (Acts 3:19).
Romans 11:7-11

What then? Israel hath not obtained that which he seeketh for; but the election hath obtained it, and the rest were blinded.
8 (According as it is written, God hath given them the spirit of slumber, eyes that they should not see, and ears that they should not hear;) unto this day.
9 And David saith, Let their table be made a snare, and a trap, and a stumblingblock, and a recompence unto them:
10 Let their eyes be darkened, that they may not see, and bow down their back alway.
11 I say then, Have they stumbled that they should fall? God forbid: but rather through their fall salvation is come unto the Gentiles, for to provoke them to jealousy.

